How to solve a optimal matching problem where the "quality" of matching is only determined once all nodes are matched
Note: I'm not a mathematician; I'm just a biologist with basic math background trying to solve a scientific problem, so please excuse my ignorance.
The gist of the problem is as follows:
I have two sets of nodes of sizes $V_1$ and $V_2$ where WLOG $|V_1|\geq|V_2|$. Now, I need to assign a set of edges E between $V_1$ and $V_2$ to create a bipartite graph with the degree of all vertices $\leq$ 1. However, the "quality" of the matching depends not on each edge but on the whole matching. Is there an algorithm known to find the optimal matching in this context?
Essentially, in the bigger context, I am trying to find the optimal way to rearrange two distance matrices or, in other words, find the optimal way to reorder the second of two distance matrices to maximize the similarity between the first and the second (reordered) matrix. This solution then needs to be extended to a set of N distance matrices to find the optimal mapping between each set of nodes.

What is the explicit formula for the quality that you want to maximize?

To me the problem looks like a special case of the quadratic assignment problem; not clear whether it simpler or harder the problem of the question

just for clarification: the value of matchings already depends on all edges, namely their sum; that is the reason why greedy algorithms may fail to yield the optimal solution. Therefore it would be important to learn more about your cost function or, what the actual problem is.

@robpratt The actual thing I want to maximize is the correlation between all the elements of the two matrices (or something similar) and for N-matrix problem, its probably gonna be the average pairwise correlation.

In which case, it should be equivalent to the QAP, right? @manfred-weis
